# smsc95xx removes assigned IP address

Tags: networking, arch-linux, raspberry-pi, network-adapter, ip-address

My setup is

- raspberry-pi 2
- archlinux

I statically assign eth0 a IP address such as `10.0.1.101`.
No matter how I do that
(via `/etc/netctl/eth0` or via cli: `ip addr add 10.0.1.101/8 dev eth0`);
every time the `smsc95xx` module detects a change on `eth0` 
(either by having done `netcl restart eth0` or physically disconnecting/connecting the ethernet cable)
it resets `eth0` and the `10.0.1.101` address is lost.

I know `smsc95xxx` is guilty because:

- every time it detects a change in `eth` a message appears (`"smsc95xx ... link down"` and later `"smsc95xx ... link up"`)
- if ip is assigned by hand (`ip addr add`) and the cable is not switched off and in,  then, IP address is kept and ping works as expected
- if ip is assigned by `netctl`, the IP address is kept until the `"sms95xx link up"` message appears.

I heavily researched on this, with no success :-(

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if there is something on

`/etc/systemd/network/`

and remove, for instance,

`eth0.network`

if so. It seems that `smsc95xx`, in some way, uses these files to
reconfigure `eth0`. Also do

`systemctl disable  dhcpcd@eth0`